# How to list call stack of all managed threads using WinDBG?

Tags: c#, .net, windbg, crash-dumps

I have a dump created from a managed application. I am using SOS/SOSEX extentions to ease my dump analysis. I'd like to list down the call stack of all managed threads as we do `~*kb` with native applications. How do we do that?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the [sos](/questions/tagged/sos) `!EEStack` command:

```
0:007> .load sos
0:007> !EEStack
```

See [SOS.dll (SOS Debugging Extension)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx)

Comment: .loadby sos clr is better (for .NET 4) or .loadby sos mscorwks

Comment: For .net 4 i downloaded the .net 4 version of sos, Psscor4 http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=21255, place the dll into the windbg folder - matching the correct dll with the correct windbg version (32bit|64bit) then to load `.load Psscor4.dll`

Comment: @sarat see JasonE's answer

Comment: `!EEStack -short`

Answer (score 38):

This command will dump all managed threads

```
~*e!dumpstack
```

Comment: Note that this requires the appropriate debugging extension to be loaded first via `.loadby sos clr`

Comment: Or `~*e!clrstack`

Answer (score 15):

with sosex, use ~*e!mk (~ - thread, * - all, e - execute this command, !mk - display managed stack. Most of the commands in sosex mirror the native command, but have the m (managed) in front of them.